# Break program if file is empty

Tags: python, file, random, break

The code below picks a random word from a file and later delete the word and its working great. I want the program to BREAK when file is empty since I delete every random word picked from the file.

Here is Random part of the code:

```
import random
import os

g = r"C:\Users\Homer\name.txt"
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(g)]
rand = random.choice(lines)       
print(rand)
```

Is it good to say Break if file is empty and print "file is empty"?
Or if Random (rand)  return no word, then break and print file is empty.

I have already checked this site and there are some answers on how to check if a file is empty and print file empty or file size is zero or there is not word in file. However, I could find one that say BREAK program if file is empty.  I get the error below when my file is empty.

```
--->rand = random.choice(lines)
IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence
```

At the  moment I'm using the code below to check if file is empty or not.  but i keep getting error with the break statement.

```
if os.path.getsize("name.txt") == 0:
    print("File is Empty")
else:
    print("File is not Empty")
    break


 ----> SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop
```

Comment: Break is used in conjunction with the continue keyword. You aren't using a loop anywhere I can see in this code. If you want the program to stop in that else block then you need `return` not `break`

Comment: You can use break only in loops. In your case just use return to terminate your program.

Comment: There's nothing to `break` in your code. Sure you didn't wantv`return`?

Comment: Additionally you can just remove the `break` and type return before your print statement. Or after, doesn't make much difference.

Comment: If you want to halt your whole program, you could raise an exception, or even just use `exit("I can't cope")`

Comment: Many thanks Guys for the solution, I just tried return instead of break but I got this error "return" outside function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your code should be (I think):

```
if os.path.getsize("name.txt") == 0:
    print("File is Empty")
else:
    return print("File is not Empty")
```

You're nearly there.

`break` is used to prematurely stop a `for` loop. The default behaviour of a loop without explicit `break` keywords is `continue` until there are no indexes left in the iterator.

You're not using a loop here. So when you ask Python to `break` there is nothing for it to stop.

Example usage of `break` keyword:

```
for x in range(20):
    if x != 13:
        print(x)
        continue # uneccesary as it will continue by default
    else:
        print("we don't like 13")
        break
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I just tried the return instead break  but I got an error saying "return" outside function.

Comment: If it's in neither a function nor a loop, what exactly is your intended outcome?

Comment: If you're running from command line then you can just `exit()` in the `else:` block I guess then.

Comment: I used try and except Error code with exit and it's working for me. Thanks for the tips, the code above and ideas. Much appreciated